# Help with c# Task class

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using WatiN to parse my web site. I have a button that starts the process. I open a browser window and navigate where I need to go, then I create a new task that calls a method called `DoWork`.

My problem is that if I call a new method at the end of `DoWork` to do something else I get strange results when I try to have the program navigate my website, however, if I don't call this new method from `DoWork` and just hook the new method up to a button click all works fine. So my question is am I not properly calling my new method from the background process method, `Dowork`?

Code:

```
IE browser = new IE("http://www.mywebsite.com/");
   string startYear;
   string endYear;
   int NumRows;
   Task myThread;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        startYear = txtStartYear.Text;
        endYear = txtEndYear.Text;
        //website navigation work removed for brevity

        browser.Button(Find.ById("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnApplyFilter")).Click();


        int numRows = browser.Div(Find.ById("scroller1")).Table(Find.First()).TableRows.Count -1;
        NumRows = numRows;
        lblTotalRows.Text = numRows.ToString();
        myThread = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork());


    }
    public void DoWork()
    {
        List<string> myList = new List<string>(NumRows);
        txtStartYear.Text = startYear;
        txtEndYear.Text = endYear;

        for (int i = 1; i < NumRows; i++)
        {
            TableRow newTable = browser.Div(Find.ById("scroller1")).Table(Find.First()).TableRows[i];
            string coll = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", newTable.TableCells[0].Text, newTable.TableCells[1].Text, newTable.TableCells[2].Text, newTable.TableCells[3].Text, newTable.TableCells[4].Text);
            myList.Add(coll);

            label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                label1.Text = i.ToString();
            });
        }
        //database work removed for brevity.

       browser.Button(Find.ById("btnFilter")).Click();

       newMethod();


    }
    public void newMethod()
    {

        int start = int.Parse(startYear);
        start++;
        startYear = start.ToString();

        int end = int.Parse(endYear);
        end++;
        endYear = end.ToString();

        browser.SelectList(Find.ById("selStartYear")).SelectByValue(startYear);
        browser.SelectList(Find.ById("selEndYear")).SelectByValue(endYear);

     //removed for brevity

    }

}
```

To reiterate, if I call `newMethod` from `Dowork` the line `browser.SelectList(Find.ById("selStartYear")).SelectByValue(startYear)` doesn't behave properly, but if I remove the call to `newMethod` from `Dowork` and just hook `newMethod` up to a button it works fine. I'm wondering if it has to do with `DoWork` being a background task?

When I say it doesn't behave properly I mean that when you select an item from the drop down list the page auto posts back, however the above line of code selects it but the page doesn't post back, which shouldn't be possible. If I don't call the method within `DoWork` I don't have this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're modifying a UI element from a non-UI thread. You've already got code which deals with that within DoWork, via `Control.Invoke` - you need to do the same kind of thing for `newMethod`. It would probably be easiest just to invoke the whole method in the UI thread:

```
// At the end of DoWork
Action action = newMethod;
label.BeginInvoke(action);
```

(I'm using `label.BeginInvoke` as I'm not sure whether the browser itself is a "normal" control - but using `label` will get to the right thread anyway. If `browser.BeginInvoke` compiles, that would be clearer.)

Comment: thankyou soooo much... So If I wasn't modifying a ui element from a non ui thread in the first place, would I still need to invoke `newMethod`?

Comment: @Nick: Assuming you weren't doing anything else that required you to be in a particular thread, it would be fine.

Comment: thanks for editing your answer and adding that last bit, that's good to know. Also, I tried browser and it doesn't work. It says WatiN core.IE does not contain a definition for `Invoke`, so there's your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's a problem with the select list control. When I browse websites, I sometimes select drop down items by keyboard. Sometimes, it just doesn't postback, while using mouse always guarantee a postback.

I think you might be better off putting an extra button and do a `browser.Button(Find.ById("btnFilter")).Click();` kind of thing to invoke a postback.

If the functions in the browser doesn't perform the proper cross thread checking, what [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) said should help.